# How to move functions to a separate file in MVVM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvvm, kendo-ui

I have following Kendo UI  MVVM. Here the business functions are written inside the `viewModel`.How can we move these functions to a different file?

The challenge I am facing is due to the `“this”` keyword inside these functions which refers the model present inside the observable.

**View Model**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var viewModel = kendo.observable({

        // model definition
        employees: [
        { name: "Lijo", age: "28" },
        { name: "Binu", age: "33" },
        { name: "Kiran", age: "29" }
        ],

        personName: "",
        personAge: "",

        //Note: Business functions  does not access any DOM elements using jquery.
        //They are referring only the objects in the view model.

        //business functions  (uses "this" keyword - e.g. this.get("employees"))
        addEmployee: function () {
            this.get("employees").push({
                name: this.get("personName"),
                age: this.get("personAge")
            });

            this.set("personName", "");
            this.set("personAge", "");
        },

        deleteEmployee: function (e) {

            //person object is created using "e"
            var person = e.data;

            var employees = this.get("employees");
            var index = employees.indexOf(person);
            employees.splice(index, 1);
        }

    });

</script>
```

**Head**

```
<head>
    <title>MVVM Test</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/kendo/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="lib/kendo/js/kendo.web.min.js"></script>

    <!----Kendo Template-->
    <script id="row-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
          <tr>
                <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
                <td data-bind="text: age"></td>
                <td><button type="button" data-bind="click: deleteEmployee">Delete</button></td>
                <td>
          </tr>
    </script>


    <!--MVVM Wiring using Kendo Binding-->
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            kendo.bind($("body"), viewModel);
        });

    </script>

</head>
```

**Body**

```
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Age
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <!--The data-template attribute tells Kendo UI that the employees objects should be formatted using a Kendo UI template. -->
        <tbody data-template="row-template" data-bind="source: employees">
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br />
    <br />
    <form>
    <input type="text" name="personName" placeholder="Name" data-bind="value: personName" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="personAge" placeholder="Age" data-bind="value: personAge" /><br />
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: addEmployee">
        Add</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

**REFERENCES**

1. [The Kendo MVVM Framework - packtpub](http://www.packtpub.com/article/the-kendo-mvvm-framework)
2. [MVVM / Remote binding -- demos.telerik](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/mvvm/remote-binding.html)
3. [DropDownList / MVVM  - demos.telerik](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/dropdownlist/mvvm.html)
4. [DataSource / Basic usage](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/datasource/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

Whether you define it in another javascript file or outside of your *kendo.observable* function, you just need to bind 'this' to the function.

This is untested but the first may work, while the second is sure to work!

```js
 function externalAddEmployee() {
    this.get("employees").push({
           name: this.get("personName"),
           age: this.get("personAge")});
    this.set("personName", "");
    this.set("personAge", "");        
}

kendo.observable({
    // first solution: may not work because the 'this' you want is not properly defined
    addEmployee: externalAddEmployee.bind(this);
    // second solution: will work everytime
    // the 'this' is properly defined, just proxy the call to the function
    addEmployee: function() { return externalAddEmployee.apply(this, arguments); }

})
```

To improve the second solution, you can even make an helper function:

```js
function proxy(fn) { return function() { return fn.apply(this, arguments); })
// and then
kendo.observable({
    addEmployee: proxy(externalAddEmployee)
})
```